# Beautiful soup not finding the same results for two different programs using the same URL

Tags: python, url, tkinter, beautifulsoup

I created a program that is played in the console. I am now making it into a GUI program. I have copied most of the code but have added in some bits for tkinter. The problem I am having is that I believe the URL does not display the same information for both programs.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def wholeProgram():

word = input("Enter a word: ")
webContent = requests.get('https://www.dictionary.com/browse/'+word)

soup = BeautifulSoup(webContent.text, 'html.parser')

global results
results = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7'})

print(results)
```

While troubleshooting, I have found that the code above prints the content found in my 'results' variable. This proves that it has successfully found this specific content on the page. But when I do the same with my other program it outputs "[]".

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


root = Tk()

askWord = Label(root, text="Enter a word")
askWord.pack()


wordEntry = Entry(root)
wordEntry.pack()
wordEntry.focus_set()

webContent = requests.get('https://www.dictionary.com/browse/'+str(wordEntry))
soup = BeautifulSoup(webContent.text, 'html.parser')

global results
results = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7'})

def callback():
   print(results)


button1 = Button(root, text="Get", width=10, command=callback)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

While searching and filtering through the page source of the URLs (eg 'view-source:https://www.dictionary.com/browse/draw'). I have found that a few sections of content do not appear in my tkinter program. I know this because while on the non-tkinter program, if you print 'webContent.text' instead of 'results', it will display the page contents and you can find 'one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7' within the content. But if you do the same with the tkinter program, you cannot find 'one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the request after the button is clicked. Also use `get()` to get the value in the [entry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) box.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = Tk()
askWord = Label(root, text="Enter a word")
askWord.pack()
wordEntry = Entry(root)
wordEntry.pack()
wordEntry.focus_set()

def callback():
    global results
    webContent = requests.get('https://www.dictionary.com/browse/'+str(wordEntry.get()))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webContent.text, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7'})
    print(results)

button1 = Button(root, text="Get", width=10, command=callback)
button1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Output for the word 'hello'

```
[<p class="one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7">He gets up and goes over to their table and introduces himself, and he says, ‘<span class="italic">Hello</span>, I’m Oliver Reed.</p>, <p class="one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7">Forty Years Young: <span class="italic">Hello</span> Kitty and the Power of Cute By Julia Rubin, Racked <span class="italic">Hello</span> Kitty is everywhere.</p>, <p class="one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7"><span class="italic">Hello</span> Ladies is, of course, about your British character navigating the L.A. dating scene.</p>, <p class="one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7">And where did the idea of the <span class="italic">Hello</span> Ladies movie come about?</p>, <p class="one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7">There was one incident that did happen that was dramatized in the <span class="italic">Hello</span> Ladies movie.</p>, <p class="one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7">Red he sees my pard passing a saloon, and he says, '<span class="italic">Hello</span>, where did you come from?</p>, <p class="one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7">And then, catching sight of Kirkwood's countenance: "Why, <span class="italic">hello</span>, Kirkwood!"</p>, <p class="one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7">"<span class="italic">Hello</span> yourself and see how you like it," the mascot of the Ravens called down.</p>, <p class="one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7">"<span class="italic">Hello</span>, old man," he cried, shaking Trenton warmly by the hand.</p>, <p class="one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7">Why couldn't he ask me how I felt or pull my ear and say "<span class="italic">Hello</span>, Puss?"</p>]
```